# canvas.lineCap and canvas.closePath not work together

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

This is my code:

```
canvas.lineCap = "round";
canvas.lineWidth = 15;
canvas.beginPath();
canvas.moveTo(100, 100);
canvas.lineTo(200, 100);
canvas.closePath();
```

If I delete `canvas.closePath()` then `canvas.lineCap` works otherwise that parameter 
not work. So what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call

```
canvas.stroke();
```

Instead of

```
canvas.closePath();
```

`canvas.closePath()` would mean you want to draw a polygon, which I assume is not the case.

Comment: So it means that I don't need to call `canvas.closePath()` when I'm drawing line?

Comment: Exactly. See this example: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_lineto.asp